# Is there a function, in python, to increment date and time, while stating a range in time?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

We're working on a project in python, where we have data stored on a MySQL database. On the database we have 2 tables, where table1 (Raw_Data) are receiving data from 2x different sources (LPN1, RisingHF) and table2 (Weather_Station) have stored from one source.

What we want to do is to subtract values, so that for example:

```
For 2019-07-26 15:00:00 to 2019-07-26 15:20:00
subtract latest data received from weather station with LPN1
subtract latest data received from weather station with RisingHF

For 2019-07-26 15:20:00 to 2019-07-26 15:40:00
subtract latest data received from weather station with LPN1
subtract latest data received from weather station with RisingHF

For 2019-07-26 15:40:00 to 2019-07-26 16:00:00
subtract latest data received from weather station with LPN1
subtract latest data received from weather station with RisingHF
```

and so on.....

We thought maybe we could increment time and date, so for example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

list_lpn = []
list_rising = []

engine = create_engine("mysql://xxx:xxx@localhost/xxx")

conn = engine.connect()
    for x in range (24):
        for y in range (0, 20, 40):
            a = pd.read.sql("SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Weather_Station WHERE timestamp > 2019-07-26 x:y:00 AND timestamp < 2019-07-26 x:y+20:00, conn) 
            b = pd.read.sql("SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = 'lpn1' AND timestamp > 2019-07-26 x:y:00 AND timestamp < 2019-07-26 x:y+20:00, conn) 
            c = pd.read.sql("SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = 'RisingHF' AND timestamp > 2019-07-26 x:y:00 AND timestamp < 2019-07-26 x:y+20:00, conn) 

            list_lpn = a - b
            list_rising = a - c
```

This code has not been implemented, but is something we have just thought about, and maybe this could be how to do it, but maybe there's a more efficient way to do this?

table1

```
  id | timestamp           | topic       | temperature | humidity | wind_speed | battery | secured | encrypted | correct |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+----------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+
| 16 | 2019-07-26 15:09:25 | lpn1        | 30.40       | 41.81    | NULL       | 3.13    |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |
| 17 | 2019-07-26 15:11:30 | rhf1s001id1 | 29.61       | 43.32    | NULL       | 3.08    |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |
| 18 | 2019-07-26 15:24:26 | lpn1        | 29.71       | 40.75    | NULL       | 3.13    |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |
| 19 | 2019-07-26 15:25:25 | rhf1s001id1 | 29.60       | 42.34    | NULL       | 3.14    |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |
| 20 | 2019-07-26 15:39:19 | rhf1s001id1 | 29.18       | 42.83    | NULL       | 3.15    |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |
| 21 | 2019-07-26 15:39:26 | lpn1        | 29.46       | 40.89    | NULL       | 3.13    |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |
| 22 | 2019-07-26 15:54:27 | lpn1        | 29.63       | 41.60    | NULL       | 3.14    |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |
| 23 | 2019-07-26 15:55:38 | rhf1s001id1 | 28.73       | 44.29    | NULL       | 3.17    |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |
```

table2

```
  id   | timestamp           | temperature1m | temperature1h | humidity1m | humidity1h |
+------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+
|    1 | 2019-07-26 15:00:13 |          26.9 |          28.3 |         44 |         48 |
|    2 | 2019-07-26 15:10:13 |            28 |          28.3 |         41 |         48 |
|    3 | 2019-07-26 15:20:13 |          27.8 |          28.3 |         39 |         48 |
|    4 | 2019-07-26 15:30:13 |            27 |          28.3 |         40 |         48 |
|    5 | 2019-07-26 15:40:13 |          26.8 |          28.3 |         42 |         48 |
|    6 | 2019-07-26 15:50:13 |            27 |          28.3 |         42 |         48 |
+------+---------------------+---------------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime() + datetime.timedelta()`

Comment: do you need only range `15:00 to 15:20` or all ranges `:00 to :20` in one query ? Maybe in SQL is function which gives only minutes from time and then you can get `minutes(timestamp) > 00 AND minutes(timestamp) < 20`. But every database may use different syntax/function to get only minutes.

Comment: Thanks, Furas! We need to subtract the values every 20 minutes all day for all the days we have data! I will look into the above. Seems interesting

Comment: o maybe you should use normal integers `y` and `y+20` and then format SQL like any other string `f"{x}:{y}:00 {x}:{y+20}:00"` or `"{}:{}:00 {}:{}:00".format(x,y,x,y+20)`

Comment: BTW: if you use `for`-loop then you don't need `x++` and `y++`.

Comment: You can also use `for y in (0, 20, 40):` to use only three values .

Comment: Thanks, Furas! Appreciating the tips. We've changed the for loop and removed x++ and y++. We're new with python. We're more used to Java and C++, so it takes some time to adjust to the pythons syntaxes

Comment: have you tried the above? does it work?

Comment: We're looking into it. We will update if succeded